# How to vanish \relax inserted by TeX itself

Tags: tex-core

TeX inserts `\relax` when it suddenly finds `\else` or `\fi` while expanding a conditional (eg, looking for a number). *TeX by Topic* says much. But how do you get rid of the `\relax` in a situation like the following fictitious example? eTeX's `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` do vanish `\relax` but perhaps not in a situation like the following.

```
\edef\x{%
  \ifnum0=0\fi\ifnum\z@=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{x}{y}%
}
```

---

**(Edited in from 'answer')**

Martin, The `\@empty` may linger even in full expansion contexts: `\noexpand` makes expandable commands recoverable `\relax`. Moreover, at least 1/2 of the time one is not interested in full expansion or printing, but in a one- or two-step expansion. The outcome may even be immediately detokenized. So any extra `\@empty` or `\space` intended as an 'artificial' stopper will linger in the definition in situations where a non-expandable token is found before the artificial stopper. The following illustrates the point of Bruno, which I had been aware of:

```
\def\test@cond#1\fi{%
  #1\noexpand\@empty
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{x}{y}%
}
\edef\x{\test@cond\ifnum\z@=\z@\fi}
\edef\x{\test@cond\if xx\fi}
\edef\x{\test@cond\ifnum0=0\fi}
```

I have found a tricky solution involving `\iffirstisspace` macro, and `\romannumeral` too offers a way out.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "TeX by Topic says much"?

Comment: When you are at this levet, the comp.text.tex news groups might be a better place to ask

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: When I looked in _TeX by Topic_ I saw where it mentions that TeX does itself insert `\relax` in some circumstances, but it says nothing about how to get rid of the `\relax` in an `\edef` context. Then I saw somewhere in an issue of TUGBoat that `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` do remove `\relax` after evaluating the dimension or number. That is indeed true, but they fail in the above example.

Comment: @Ahmed: Maybe you could give a precise reference where this is written in TeX by Topic?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: TeX by Topic, Section 12.5.3, page 104 (2001 edition).

Comment: @Ahmed: Thanks, found it. Strangely enough I didn't find anything in the TeXbook.

Answer (score 6):

TeX stops looking for a number e.g. when it finds a space which is then consumed.
Therefore your example could be fixed like this:

```
\edef\x{%
  \ifnum0=0 \fi\ifnum\z@=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{x}{y}%
}
```

However, in the general case it might not be so easy:

```
\edef\x{%
  \ifnum\macroa=\macrob \fi\ifnum\z@=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{x}{y}%
}
```

If `\macrob` doesn't end with a space the relax is still inserted. Adding a normal space after it is of course removed like any other space after command sequences. Adding an explicit `\space` would work as long `\macrob` doesn't end with one, otherwise it will not be removed and be part of the definition.

Here helps eTeX with `\numexpr` which can be used with `\relax` as an end-marker:

```
\edef\x{%
  \ifnum\macroa=\numexpr\macrob\relax\fi\ifnum\z@=\z@
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{x}{y}%
}
```

Then `\macrob` works independent if it contains a trailing space or not.

So I think the answer to your question "How to vanish `\relax` inserted by TeX itself" is: don't let TeX insert one in the first place by avoiding the situation.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. I already knew about the space stopper and much of what you have said. Don't allow TeX to insert `\relax`: good! But sometimes you want to cnstruct a general macro to test all types of conditions, including explicit numbers (that are not macros, `\dimendef`'d, `\countdef`'d or `\skipdef`d).

Comment: @Ahmed: I thought that you knew most of the things I stated. I added it so that others can follow. Just had this idea: `\ifnum0=0\noexpand\empty\fi` which works for avoiding the implicit `\relax`.

Comment: Clever idea of using `\noexpand\empty`!

Comment: But it would not work if you replace the second `0` by `0\space` (perhaps hidden in a macro).

Comment: @Bruno: Yes, than `\x` would contain `\empty` but it would still be fully expandable.