# \ifcsname x\endcsname when it isn't apparent that \x was made \relax

Tags: tex-core

A few days ago I tried to point out to Will Robertson one of the pitfalls of eTeX’s `\ifcsname` and `\ifdefined` but he didn’t seem to get the message. Please am I right in saying that the following beckons us to be cautious when using`\ifcsname` and `\ifdefined`, since they return 'true' when a command is made `\relax`? Tests like **etoolbox**'s `\ifdef` and `\ifcsdef` should be preferred when the aim is to test if a command is equivalent to `\undefined`.

With the hope of later doing, e.g., `\expandafter<cmd>\x`, I defined

```
\edef\x{\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname test@\romannumeral\currentgrouplevel\endcsname}}
```

After some intervening code, I then did

```
\ifcsname test@\romannumeral\currentgrouplevel\endcsname
  \def\y{Yes}
\else
  \def\y{No}
\fi
\show\y
```

On the face of it, there was no apparent relation between defining `\x` and the later test. I first wondered where `test@\romannumeral\currentgrouplevel` was defined. It took me some time to locate the problem.

Comment: Two rather separate issues here: could you post the `\edef\x{\ifnum0=0\else\fi}` separately, and perhaps give this one a clearer name?

Comment: I agree with @Joseph on both accounts. Also, the second question is quite related to your existing question [How to vanish \relax inserted by TeX itself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14247/how-to-vanish-relax-inserted-by-tex-itself). TeX inserts an implicit `\relax` because it finds `\else` in *number reading* mode which needs to be terminated then.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thank you for the reference. The question I should actually be asking is why is it that with `\edef\x{\ifnum0=0\else\fi}` being `\relax` and `\def\y{\relax}`, we see that `\ifx\x\y` is false? Are there two types of `\relax`?

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Yes, apparently the *implicit relax* has a different definition. This has been once a [topic in one of the chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/345/conversation/implicit-relax). (Edit: now better link)

Comment: @AhmedMusa I can transfer the second part of my answer, if you make a new question.

Comment: It beckons us to be careful with \csname ... \endcsname because that does define the cs (which is precisely why the eTeX developers added the new primitives to allow for an expandable test that doesn't define the cs). So perhaps you should reword the start of your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not misleading because it follows the precisely laid out rules.

1. When `\csname` is expanded, TeX looks for the matching `\endcsname` with expansion; then TeX forms a control sequence token from the character tokens (irrespective of category code) it has found or issues an error if some non character token is discovered.
2. After the formation of the token, TeX looks up in its memory to find if that token has a meaning. If it hasn't, that token is made equivalent to `\relax` with a local assignment.
3. `\edef` expands the tokens it finds between the braces that delimit the replacement text before storing the resulting `<balanced text>` as the replacement text.

Thus your `\edef\x{\csname totallyundefined\endcsname}` is equivalent to

```
\let\totallyundefined\relax
\def\x{\totallyundefined}
```

On the contrary, the `\ifdefined` and `\ifcsname` tests (by precise choice of e-TeX's developers) never perform the assignment to `\relax` of an undefined token.

The `\relax` assignment is performed in *many* other cases as a precaution against premature expansions. Two cases mentioned in the TeXbook are

```
\chardef\cs=10\cs
\font\cs=name\cs
```

where `\cs` is temporarily made equivalent to `\relax` in order to stop expansion when the assignment is performed. In such cases it's really temporary, as `\cs` will immediately be assigned a new meaning; in the case of `\csname` it isn't. Where's the problem? If `\cs` had a previous definition, without the temporary assignment to `\relax`, TeX would expand `\cs` searching for a number in the first case or the end of the file name in the second. Even worse, if `\cs` was undefined, an error would be raised, because TeX hasn't yet assigned to `\cs` the new meaning. Of course, using such a syntax is discouraged.

It may be unfortunate that e-TeX uses `\ifcsname...\endcsname` with the same rules of `\csname...\endcsname` for the formation of the token to be examined, but with the fundamental difference that the equivalence to `\relax` is not performed, but that's what it is.

---

In the case you're presenting, that is

```
\edef\x{\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname test@\romannumeral\currentgrouplevel\endcsname}}
```

you might do it indirectly:

```
\edef\x{\noexpand\csname @test\romannumeral\currentgrouplevel\endcsname}
```

so that the `\csname` won't be executed. Of course `\x` would need two expansions steps:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cs\x
```

Comment: `\endcsname` is unexpandable, so you don't need that second `\noexpand` in your last example.

Comment: @egreg: `\chardef\cs=10\cs` gives `{\char"A}\everypar->\@nodocument` outside `\document`. This syntax should be qualified.

Comment: @AhmedMusa This is a Plain TeX example. Of course you get an error if use that in the preamble of a LaTeX document, because you're trying to typeset a character.

Answer (score 9):

Both `\ifcsname` and `\ifdefined` test if the control sequence is *defined* at all, this includes control sequences which are equal to `\relax`. Earlier tests use `\expandafter\ifx\csname abc\endcsname\relax` which uses the feature of `\csname` to define undefined control sequences automatically to be equal to relax.
You are right that *mixing* these two ways to test is dangerous, because any `\ifx\csname` test or other `\csname` on the same name will change the outcome of the other two tests on the same control sequence, because it is now defined equal to `\relax`.
Both `\ifcsname` and `\ifdefined` intensionally do not define the control sequence to `\relax` and should actually be preferred over `\ifx\csname`, but you might only want them to use with control sequences your package etc. defines itself where no other code tested it using a different test.

BTW: You can use grouping like: `\begingroup\expandafter\ifx\csname abc\endcsname\relax\endgroup ..\else\endgroup .. \fi`, to keep the `\csname` definition local, but the LaTeX core macro `\@ifundefined` doesn't do that.

Comment: The problem with Heiko-style `\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup \expandafter\ifx\csname x\endcsname ...` is that it isn't expandable.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Yes, I know. I was thinking mentioning that, but the question didn't mentioned expandability so I didn't.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if the second part of the question will be migrated but here is an explanation in any case.

The expansion of `\ifnum...\fi` is empty if the test is false, `\relax` otherwise, thus the
meaning of

```
   `\edef\x{\ifnum0=0\fi}`
```

is

```
   `macro:->\relax`
```

Try this test for fun:

```
    {\def\relax{0}\xdef\foo{\ifnum0=0\fi}}
```

This puts `\relax` in `\foo`. Although tricky, this token is not the same token as the one that follows the `\def`, since otherwise `0\fi` would expand to `0\relax\fi` then `00\fi`, then `00\relax\fi` without end (and without overflow).

This behaviour is not an oddity, but a mind boggling fact!

Comment: Sorry, but the explanation is incorrect: with `\edef\x{\ifnum0=0 \fi}` the expansion of `\x` is empty.

Comment: @egreg Not on my computer! Try `\edef\x{\ifnum0=0\fi}
\tt
\meaning\x
\bye`

Comment: You didn't notice the space before `\fi`.

Comment: @egreg True if you leave a space or an `A` for example but I don't see why you say the explanation is incorrect.

Comment: The correct explanation is "unfinished conditional" and "frozen `\relax`" that I learnt from David Kastrup.

Comment: You should cut-and-paste this answer to [Normal \relax vs. frozen \relax](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57412)