# Normal \relax vs. frozen \relax

Tags: tex-core

With

```
\edef\x{\ifnum0=0\else\fi}
```

being `\relax` and with

```
\def\y{\relax}
```

we see that `\ifx\x\y` is false. Why?

See also [\ifcsname x\endcsname when it isn't apparent that \x was made \relax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57398/ifcsname-when-it-isnt-apparent-that-the-command-is-relaxed).

Comment: See also [this related chat discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/345/conversation/implicit-relax). Apparently the special relax has a different definition than the normal one.

Comment: On the other hand, `\expandafter\ifx\x\relax` is true. This works for all primitives that have a frozen version and therefore appear twice in the equivalence table. With LuaTeX, you can create additional copies of primitives using `tex.enableprimitives`, and they show the same behavior.

Comment: Generally speaking, `\ifx` only looks one level deep: it checks whether all tokens have the same indices into the equivalence table, but does not check whether they have the same meaning. The same works with `\let\foo=\relax`: Now `\foo` is a token with the meaning of `\relax` but a different name.

Comment: Does pdfTeX have something similar to `tex.enableprimitives`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's look at the transcript of an interactive session with TeX.

```
> tex
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
**\relax

*\def\x{\relax}

*\edef\y{\ifnum0=0\fi}

*\show\x
> \x=macro:
->\relax .
<*> \show\x

?      

*\show\y
> \y=macro:
->\relax .
<*> \show\y

? 

*\ifx\x\y\message{EQUAL}\else\message{UNEQUAL}\fi
UNEQUAL

*\edef\z{\ifnum0=0 \fi}

*\show\z
> \z=macro:
->.
<*> \show\z

? 

*\bye
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Why aren't `\x` and `\y` equivalent? And why aren't `\y` and `\z` equivalent in the first place?

The conditionals

```
\ifnum0=0\fi
```

or

```
\ifnum0=0\else\fi
```

are pretty much the same and the fact that `\y` becomes nonempty stems down from another precaution that TeX takes against premature expansion.

When TeX is looking for a `<number>` it expands tokens as it goes. But in this case it finds a `\fi` or an `\else` that matches the `\ifnum` while the search for the second number to test is still *unfinished*. Were it to expand the `\fi` or `\else` everything bad might happen. So, in this cases, TeX inserts a "safe" token that it represents on the terminal with `\relax` but is in fact *not* the same `\relax` that we know and are allowed to use. For instance, you can't redefine this token:

```
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011)
**\relax

*\edef\x{\ifnum0=0\fi}

*\expandafter\def\x{Something}
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
<*> \expandafter\def\x
                      {Something}
```

One is not allowed to feed the "frozen relax" token to `\def`, as it is evident from the above interactive session.

The problem does not show with

```
\edef\z{\ifnum0=0 \fi}
```

because the lookup for the `<number>` is terminated by the space token (which is then ignored). Therefore this is just a complicated way to say

```
\def\z{}
```

Note. With `\edef\Z{\ifnum0=1\else\fi}` or `\edef\Z{\ifnum0=1\fi}` the expansion of `\Z` would be empty, because the "frozen relax" token becomes part of the "true branch" and so it disappears.

### When is TeX inserting the "frozen relax"?

TeX keeps track of the nesting of conditionals and the insertion of the frozen relax happens when an `\else` or `\fi` is encountered at the same level as the conditional it's being evaluated *and* the process of expansion for this evaluation hasn't yet finished.

So, for instance, TeX adds one in

```
\ifnum0=1\else\fi
```

because a `<number>` is collected by expanding the following tokens. Another case is

```
\if\fi
```

which results in an empty expansion because *two* frozen relax tokens are inserted, which are equal as far as `\if` is concerned. Also

```
\if\relax\fi
```

inserts a frozen relax, but again, `\if` compares `\relax` to the frozen relax token and the test returns truth.

Answer (score 2):

In simpler language, there are two TeX scanning rules to keep in mind:

1)  The expansion of `\ifnum...\fi` is *empty* <sup>a</sup> if the test is false, `\relax (frozen)` otherwise.

```
   true condtion -> \relax (frozen)
   false condition -> empty
```

2)  TeX when reading integers will read until it finds something unexpandable such as a space.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\tracingall
\count0=5
\count13=5
\count0=2\ifnum\count0=\count1 3 some words\fi9\par%false->empty 
\the\count0 %29
\bye
```

Here, we see both rules in operation, TeX is trying to put a value into `\count0=2`, but continues to scan until it finds an unexpandable token. It encounters the conditional. It evaluates the condition (which is false) and as per rule 1) the `ifnum..\fi` are let to empty.
The scanning is then completed and count0=2{empty}9, hence 29.

Modifying the MWE to complete the discussion `(\ifnum\count0=\count13)`.

```
\tracingall
\count0=5
\count13=5
\count0=2\ifnum\count0=\count13 some words\fi9\par% true>\relax  prints some words 9
\the\count0 % has the value of 2
\bye
```

If you have a conditional in an `\edef`, it behaves exactly the same way as `edef` expands its contents. The second part of your question stems from the fact that the relax inserted by TeX is a "frozen" relax and hard-coded into the engine. (See example at the bottom of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57404/963).

<sup>a</sup> It appears that egreg and David Kastrup call this emptiness and the `\relax`  an *unfinished conditional*.

Comment: Sorry, but your assertion about the expansion of `\ifnum` is still incorrect. The "frozen relax" is inserted *only* in some cases and `\edef\x{\ifnum0=0 \else\fi}` results in an empty meaning for `\x` even if the test is true.

Comment: @egreg empty meaning or space? Can you expand on the _only_?

Comment: The "frozen" relax is inserted only when TeX finds an `\else` or `\fi` at the same level as the conditional it's evaluating, while collecting tokens to proceed to the evaluation. In the example I've given the expansion of `\x` is *empty*, because the space after the second `0` is ignored by rule.