# \ifnum expanding too much - what is happening?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, expansion

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fail[1]{%
    \ifnum1=#1% <- here a space is missing
        \expandafter \@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter \@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \fail{1}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

With 1=1 it prints false, with 1=2 it prints truefalse.

I know that this is a problem of `\ifnum` expanding too much hoping to find  a continuation of the number and that this can be fixed by inserting a space after `#1`.

However, I do not understand what exactly is happening.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57417/120953) seems related but I am still unable to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL;DR

Never forget a space after a constant, unless you know *precisely* why you omit it (the `\romannumeral` trick is a prime example of why one might want to omit a space after a constant).

## What happens?

What happens is that, due to the lack of a terminator for the number being evaluated, `\expandafter` is expanded; this touches `\else`, so, by rule, TeX inserts `\relax` (the “frozen” type) in front of `\else` (note that `\expandafter` has already gone). See [Normal \relax vs. frozen \relax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57412/4427).

Thus you get the same as

```
\ifnum1=1\@firstoftwo\relax\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{true}{false}
```

Now expansion resumes, because the number is still unfinished and `\@firstoftwo` returns `\relax`; the test is then evaluated to true so TeX remains with

```
\relax\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{true}{false}
```

The `\relax` token is executed (or stored in the case of `\edef`) and `\else` is gobbled up and we get

```
《\relax》\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{true}{false}
```

Now `\expandafter` removes `\fi` and you end up with

```
《\relax》\@secondoftwo{true}{false}
```

so finally `\relax false`. If you do

```
\edef\test{\fail{1}{true}{false}}\show\test
```

the terminal will indeed show

```
> \test=macro:
->\relax false.
```

If you add `\tracingmacros=1` before the call to `\fail`, the log file will show

```
\fail #1->\ifnum 1=#1\expandafter \@firstoftwo \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi 
#1<-1

\@firstoftwo #1#2->#1
#1<-\relax 
#2<-\else 

\@secondoftwo #1#2->#2
#1<-true
#2<-false
```

confirming my analysis.

With `《...》` I denote tokens that have already been sent to the further level.

If the call is `\fail{2}{true}{false}`, the first step yields

```
\ifnum1=2\@firstoftwo\relax\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{true}{false}
```

Since the number is not yet finished, `\@firstoftwo` is expanded, returning `\relax`:

```
\ifnum1=2\relax\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{true}{false}
```

The test now can be evaluated to false, so everything up to `\fi` (as `\else` no longer is present) is removed without expansion, leading to

```
\fi{true}{false}
```

and `\fi` now disappears. Indeed, `\edef\test{\fail{2}{true}{false}}\show\test` prints

```
> \test=macro:
->{true}{false}.
```

on the terminal.

What about if you exchange `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fail[1]{%
    \ifnum1=#1% <- here a space is missing
        \expandafter \@secondoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter \@firstoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\edef\test{\fail{1}{false}{true}}\show\test

\tracingmacros=1 \tracingonline=1

    \fail{1}{false}{true}

\tracingmacros=0

\end{document}
```

Now the first level expansion will again add `\relax`, but we get

```
\ifnum1=1\@secondoftwo\relax\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi{false}{true}
```

As before, `\@secondoftwo` is expanded, returning `\else`. Oh, but the number is yet unfinished, so a further frozen `\relax` is added, to yield

```
\ifnum1=1\relax\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi{false}{true}
```

Now the conditional is evaluated to true, and the test is removed:

```
\relax\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi{false}{true}
```

As before, `\relax` is sent down to the stomach and `\else` removes all tokens up to the matching `\fi`, without expansion:

```
《\relax》\fi{false}{true}
```

The `\fi` disappears and we remain with the equivalent of

```
\relax{false}{true}
```

Comment: now I see. And in the other case, with 1=2, `\@firstoftwo` gobbles the `\else` in the same way so that TeX discards everything until `\fi` when reading the `\relax` and evaluating `\ifnum`. Therefore the two groups `{true}{false}` remain untouched and are printed to the pdf. Thank you.

Comment: @jakun I added some further analysis and fixed a weakness in the description.