# \edef\relax{\relax} makes \relax hang forever

Tags: macros, tex-core, definition

Previously I thought it is always safe to `\edef` a macro to its existing definition. But `\edef\relax{\relax}` makes `\relax` hang forever and CPU is very busy. So what is TeX doing there?

Comment: this is an explicit infinite recursion, but what was the intention? Or is the answer simply "don't do that"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No there is no intention. As I said I thought `\edef{<same_macro>}{<same_macro>}` is always safe but this one is a counterexample.

Comment: It isn't really a counter example, as `\relax` is not a macro (it's an unexpandable primitive) But most macros are not safe in an `\edef` either but would fail in other ways, either in the edef itself or when used after the definition.

Comment: The \edef itself is safe. Try inside a group: `{\edef\relax{\relax}}` the problem is the later use of the redefined command (which will happen sooner or later, as every document has lots of \relax in the code).

Comment: as @UlrikeFischer says the edef here does not error just redefines `\relax` to loop, but if you try it with a macro typically you will get errors in the edef, try `\edef\section{\section}` for example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\relax` is not expandable so this is the same as `\def\relax{\relax}` as you can check with `\show\relax`.  So then any use of `\relax` will cause it to expand in one step to `\relax` and so be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 10):

It's definitely *unsafe* to do `\edef\foo{\foo}` if by “safe” you mean “to get the same as before”.

Suppose you have

```
\newif\ifblurb
\def\foo{\ifblurb A\else B\fi}
```

then doing

```
\edef\foo{\foo}
```

will not yield the same definition of `\foo` as before; since a conditional starts out false, your `\edef` would be the same as

```
\def\foo{B}
```

whereas if given after `\blurbtrue` it would be equivalent to

```
\def\foo{A}
```

In other words, you get the “expanded” version of the replacement text, which may or may not be what you'd think.

There is something else to take into account: when TeX processes `\edef`, it first puts apart the macro name and the parameter text, then fully expands the given replacement text until only unexpandable tokens remain; each macro is expanded with its current value; once the new replacement text has been obtained, TeX does `\def` using it along with the original tokens in the parameter text.

Since `\relax` is not expandable, your definition turns out to be the same as `\def\relax{\relax}`. Note that after this `\relax` has become a *macro* rather than the primitive.

When later you say `\relax`, TeX knows it is a macro and expands it according to its definition, so it replaces it with `\relax` and restarts expansion…

Comment: OK I understand why `\edef` doesn't keep things intact: it redefines with an "expanded" body instead of the body itself. But I was a bit surprised when the compiler didn't warn me when I redefined a primitive. Aren't there any reserved keywords there in tex such that cannot be redefined?

Comment: @Cyker No, nothing is reserved except a few internal tokens that are quite difficult to access. As you discovered, it's easy to shoot on one's foot…

Comment: @Cyker You can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57417/4427 for one of those internal tokens; the “frozen `\relax`” token cannot be redefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asserts that `\edef\relax{\relax}` on its own causes an infinite loop. But it is not so:

```
C:\Users\hammerite>tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)
**\relax

*\edef\relax{\relax}

*
```

TeX prints the * prompt immediately after executing the line containing `\edef\relax{\relax}`, so it didn't go into a loop at all. You are mistaken.

Comment: You are right. The definition itself doesn't hang. Actually I mean the redefined `\relax` hangs. This is updated now.