# How do I generate a warning for an undefined control sequence

Tags: macros, warnings

I've defined some setter and getter commands to facilitate entering complex content into my document.  The basic definitions are as follows:

```
\newcommand\aeset[3]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname ae@#1@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\aeget[2]{\csname ae@#1@#2\endcsname}
```

The problem I'm having is that if define the following

```
\aeset{this}{is}{an experiment}
```

and then later try to call it with

```
\aeget{that}{is}
```

The command just expands into a `\relax` without issuing a warning that

```
\ae@that@is
```

is not a defined control sequence.  Is there a simple way to get around this without having to manually write all the testing arguments into my getter?

Comment: Test it using the conditionals from **etoolbox**?

Comment: Related: [`\ifcsname x\endcsname` when it isn't apparent that `\x` was made `\relax`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57398/5764)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\ifcsname...\endcsname`, which tests both for an undefined or a `\relax` control sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeset[3]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname ae@#1@#2\endcsname{#3}}
\newcommand\aeget[2]{%
  \ifcsname ae@#1@#2\endcsname
    \csname ae@#1@#2\endcsname
  \else
    \@latex@warning{`\string\ae{#1}{#2}' does not exist}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aeset{this}{is}{an experiment}%

get:\aeget{that}{is}

\end{document}
```

The above produces the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: `\ae{that}{is}' does not exist on input line 18.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aeset[3]{\@namedef{ae@#1@#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*\aeget[2]{%
  \ifcsname ae@#1@#2\endcsname\@nameuse{ae@#1@#2}
    \else\@latex@warning{`\string\ae{#1}{#2}' does not exist} undefined!!!\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
    \aeset{this}{is}{an experiment} 

    get: \aeget{this}{is} 

    get: \aeget{that}{is}   
\end{document}
```

[image]