# how to throw a warning in latex?

Tags: warnings, debugging, error-writing

I want to know how to throw a warning when latex reach to a certain point.

For instance:

```
\switch [\exp1]
\case{{case 0}}
        %do whatever
\case{{case 1}}
        %do whatever
\otherwise
        %throw warning
\endswitch
```

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Are the cases referring to numbers? Or could this be general text?

Comment: it can be whatever, my main concern is how to throw the warning given you get to some point (in the example, would be the _otherwise_)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How do I generate a warning for an undefined control sequence](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/283961/5764)

Comment: You are right! I was not able to find that question when I searched :(. However, I think @Heiko Oberdiek's answer to this one is more complete than the ones there! :)

Comment: Somewhat special case of [macros - Is there any way to generate custom errors/warnings in LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/is-there-any-way-to-generate-custom-errors-warnings-in-latex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX provides warnings, which are printed to the console/`.log` file, both with including the current line number and without.

A class has:

```
\ClassWarning{<class name>}{<message>}
\ClassWarningNoLine{<class name>}{<message>}
```

A package has:

```
\PackageWarning{<package name>}{<message>}
\PackageWarningNoLine{<package name>}{<message>}
```

LaTeX uses:

```
\@latex@warning{<message>}
\@latex@warning@no@line{<message>}
```

The documentation can be found in "[LaTeX2e for class and package writers](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/clsguide.pdf)" (`texdoc clsguide`).

Answer (score 2):

TeX (in all formats) provides messages, which are printed to the console/.log file.

```
\wlog{text}   % prints expanded text to log only, CR added
```

You can define `\def\wterm{\immediate \write16 }` and then:

```
\wterm{text}  % prints expanded text to terminal and to the log, CR added
```

There is `\message` primitive:

```
 \message{text} % prints expanded text to terminal and to the log, no CR added
```

Note that `\the\inputlineno` expands to the current line number of the input file.